# How to change font color on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a button animation on hover pseudo element. While the fill works fine, the font color does not change. I am sure this is something silly on my part, can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Will appreciate a lot is someone could point me in the right direction.

code pen example here

https://codepen.io/sabarishiyer/pen/RwaOJyO

code

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 10px
}

body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #272838
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aquamarine;
  border: 3px solid aquamarine;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  /*To position pseudo elements relative to the button*/
  transition: all 1s;
}

.button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: aquamarine;
  background-color: white;
}

.button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: aquamarine;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #272838;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.button:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <a class="button" href="#">Learn more</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is not the text color, it is the z-index. add this:

```
.button::after,
.button::before {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: It is indeed..Thanks all for the answers. I never understood z-index tbh..

Answer (score 2):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 10px
}

body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #272838
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aquamarine;
  border: 3px solid aquamarine;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  /*To position pseudo elements relative to the button*/
  transition: all 1s;
}

.button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: aquamarine;
  background-color: white;
}

.button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: aquamarine;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #272838;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.button:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <a class="button" href="#">Learn more</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Adding the `z-index: -1` to `.button` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

use `z-index: -1;`

```
.button::before {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: aquamarine;
}
```